# Swift 3.0: Type of Expression is ambiguous without more context?

Tags: ios, swift, expression

```
private func makeRequest<T where T:MappableNetwork>(method method: Alamofire.Method, url: String,
                         parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, keyPath: String, handler: NetworkHandler<T>.handlerArray) -> Request {

    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "",
        ]

    return Alamofire
        .request(method, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseArray(keyPath: keyPath) { (response: Alamofire.Response<[T], NSError>) in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                if let data = response.data {
                    let error = self.getError(data)
                    if error != nil {
                        handler(.Error(error: error!))
                        return
                    }
                }
                handler(.Error(error: error))
            } else if let objects = response.result.value {
                handler(.Success(data: objects))
            }
    }
}
```

I converted code swift 2.x to 3.x and I getting error Type expression is ambiguous without more context.

[image]

Comment: What does the handler expect to get? You start with a period (.) and it cannot be determined automatically in that case, what should be before the period?

Comment: ok I got your point. let try that. thanks @Yitzchak

Comment: Did it worked? Can I post the answer? Share us exactly what was missing?

Comment: yes its works @Yitzchak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you mentioned tells you that the compiler cannot determine the exact type of the value you entered.

You started with a period, something has to be before the period. Sometimes the compiler can understand without your help. That's not this case, it has several options so it's ambiguous and it asks you to tell exactly the class name that you meant.

Comment: @Josh Glad to here :) but can you edit your comment so that we understand what is your change that fixed the issue? Also, if it helped you, consider to upvote ;)

Comment: My comment was nonsense, I was already exhausted, sorry for that.